# Is there any way to change the mouse cursor/pointer style for android?

Tags: android, styles, mouse-cursor

As we know some tablet could plug in usb mouse. Is there any way can change the pointer to some other image, like replace some icon with some picture like it could be done in windows or linux.

what ever way will be fine.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not via the Android SDK. Presumably you can change this via custom firmware, though such a change, by default, would be for the entire device (and, of course, only devices running that custom firmware).

Comment: So does that means the only way to change the mouse pointer style is change the aosp code and rebuild it? Thank you.

Comment: @user1131441: At the present time, yes.

Comment: If that, may I ask you which part this "pointer" stored? Mouse driver? There must be a part contain this "pointer" somewhere in the source code. Does google tell that? Or any hacker tells?

Comment: @user1131441: I have no idea, sorry.